# how to customize ObjectListField?

Tags: listview, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to customize Objectfieldlist according to following design?

```
         ----------------------------
ROW#1    ROW NAME
         row details
         ---------------------------
ROW#2    ROW NAME
         row details
         ---------------------------  
ROW#3    ROW NAME
         row details
         ---------------------------
```

Row Name will be in bigger font than row details

Basically I need 2 text rows in a Row of ObjectListField.**OR any other method or suggestion as I might be wrong,**pls guide me its urgent and am some what new to Blackberry Development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ObjectListField` isn't really the right way to do this - it's really designed as a quick version of `ListField` for those times when you just need a simple list of strings.

You should extend `ListField` itself, and provide your own implementation of `ListFieldCallback` that renders your list based on your data model.  Use `ListField.setCallback` to set your callback.

`ListFieldCallback.drawListRow` gives you a `Graphics` context, so you can draw whatever you want, including multiple lines of text.  Also make sure to call `ListField.setRowHeight` on your listfield to make the rows high enough for 2 lines of text (the default height is the font height, so you'd only have room for 1 line of text).

Sample code is something like (this is not complete and will not compile without some other code):

```
ListField myListField = new ListField();
myListField.setRowHeight(getFont().getHeight() * 2)

myListField.setCallback(new ListFieldCallback() {
    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width) {
       // draw the first line of text
       graphics.drawText(0, y, "ROW " + rowNumber);
       graphics.drawText(20, y, "ROW NAME");
       graphics.drawText(20, y + getFont().getHeight(), "row details"); 
    }
```